# Polygons from line segments

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph, polygon, convex-hull

I have a list of line segments in no particular order.

I want to find all enclosed spaces (polygons) formed by the segments. Is there an efficient algorithm or method that I could use to do this?

The following image illustrates the problem. How can I detect the green polygons, given the black line segments?

[image: How do find polygons (green) from line segments?]

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to build a graph as follows:

- the nodes are the intersection points of the edges
- there's an edge between nodes *i* and *j* iff points *i* and *j* are on the same edge

Once you've built the graph:

- Run the [Connected Components Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_%28graph_theory%29) on it, and check for connected components of size > 2
- Run a [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) algorithm on the intersection points within such a component

**Edit** modified from original due to excellent point by FooBar.

Comment: One edge case for the connected Components would be an edge that divides an area (so that it is part of several connected components).

Comment: And what is the goal of the convex hull step? What happens for a non convex area?

Comment: @FooBar That's a question for the OP, I think.

Comment: If theres 2 squares apart that share a line your algorithm would construct big rectangle instead of 2 squares.

Comment: using bi-connected components instead seems to work

Comment: @photon I agree that it seems that bi-connected components seems better. In the shown graph all the green areas seem to be part of the same connected component, but split into three different bi-connected components.

Answer (score 2):

This is indeed a classical problem in [computational geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_geometry).

Your are looking for the `faces` of an [arrangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrangement_of_lines) of your segments.

For a discussion of this topics with (too many) details, and source code, there is this wonderful library: [CGAL](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Arrangement_on_surface_2/index.html) .

Note that you'll have to decide what you do for e.g. a polygon inside another, many polygons intertwined, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Ami's answer is a good pointer in the correct direction, but here are the more detailed steps you might need to know about:

1. Take the list of line segments and build a collection of vertexes. Since check each individual segment for intersections with each other segment is basically a N^2 operation when done via brute force, you might want to build a quad-tree and use that to reduce the number of checks you are performing. If n is small or you have a lot of cpu time to burn, just brute force it, otherwise you need to be clever about your collision detection. Here is a library that implements quad-tree collision detection: https://github.com/hroger1030/SpatialTrees
2. With your list of nodes and edges, you have the pieces to build a graph. you can call your lines nodes and the intersections the edges or vice-versa, it kind of doesn't matter. The important thing is you can now just go find all the cycles on the graph where the number of nodes in the cycle > 2.

I just so happens that I wrote an implementation of Tarjan Cycle detection in c#: [Tarjan cycle detection help C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643076/tarjan-cycle-detection-help-c-sharp/36489758#36489758). This might be an alternative to the suggested Connected Components Algorithm.

Comment: Once you have identified it? I have no idea, I don't know what you are going to do with it once you have identified it. You need to figure that out, there are many ways to represent polygons.